# How to compute the number of param of a simple deep network in a greyscale image

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

How to compute the number of weight of CNN in a greyscale image.

here is the code:

Define input image size

```
input_shape = (32, 32, 1)
flat_input_size = input_shape[0]*input_shape[1]*input_shape[2]
num_classes = 4
```

Simple deep network

```
dnn_model = Sequential()
dnn_model.add(Dense(input_dim=flat_input_size, units=1000))
dnn_model.add(Activation("relu"))
dnn_model.add(Dense(units=512))
dnn_model.add(Activation("relu"))
dnn_model.add(Dense(units=256))
dnn_model.add(Activation("relu"))
dnn_model.add(Dense(units=num_classes))
dnn_model.add(Activation("softmax"))
```

The picture below is the network plot
[image]

here is the result
[image]

count anyone help me to compute the number of params.
how to get 1025000, 512512, 131328, 1028, show some details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a dense layer with bias (the bias is the +1) the calculation is as follows:

```
(input_neurons + 1) * output_neurons
```

In your case for the first layer this is:

```
(32 * 32 + 1) * 1000 = 1025000
```

and for the second one:

```
(1000 + 1) * 512 = 512512
```

and so on and so forth.

Edited answer to reflect additional question in comments:

For convolutional layers, as asked in the comments, you try to learn a filter kernel for each input channel for each output channel with an additional bias. Therefore the amount of parameters in there are:

```
kernel_width * kernel_height * input_channels * output_channels + output_channels = num_parameters
```

For your example, where we go from a feature map of size (None, 16, 16, 32) to (None, 14, 14, 64) with a (3, 3) kernel we get the following calculation:

```
3 * 3 * 32 * 64 + 64 = 18496
```

That is actually the important thing in CNNs, that the number of parameters is independent of the image size.

Comment: thanks, it helps a lot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50158474/how-to-calculate-the-total-number-of-parameters-in-a-convolutional-neural-networ, I found a more complex question about computing the params, I cannot get the correct answer, can you explain it?

Comment: Edited answer to reflect additional question.